# Redirecting process input and out through TCP socket

Tags: c, tcp

So I have a file to execute(standard C executable) and I'd like to redirect its output and input through a TCP socket. I'm already using the TCP socket to send and write messages through the server (the one that processes the executable) and the client(it sends the executables).

```
dup2(job->socket,STDOUT_FILENO);
dup2(job->socket,STDIN_FILENO);
```

This is what I've been using the redirect the input and output of the executable, however this completely screws up the server reading part of the socket(as expected).

I cannot open a new socket for this so I was wondering how I could do this?